# Subsetting data frame based on vector/list in R

Tags: r, filter, subset

I have 5k rows of data which follows the following:

| Name | Year | Concentration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2014 | 12 |
| B | 2014 | 34 |
| C | 2014 | 21 |
| C | 2014 | 231 |
| A | 2015 | 123 |
| B | 2015 | 43 |
| B | 2015 | 42 |

Names repeat all over the years to 2023. I want to subset to make a table only with selected names.

I made a list or vector:

```
a<-c('A','B')
df_list<-df[df$Name == a,]
df_list<-subset(df, df$Name == a)
```

None of this works.
The second try, gives a result where it tries to pick the names in the List for each year and that's it. The problem is for a given year i have more than one observation in that given year in respect to A or B.

Comment: Use `subset(df, Name %in% a)`

Comment: or `df[df$Name %in% a]`